# Is a multi-model database a good solution for storing frequently updated data alongside referential WORM data?

Tags: nosql, rdbms, multi-model-database

I'm working on an application that frequently requires data updates. An RDBMS meets our needs but future product strategy will require storage of static referential domain data and a lot of cross-referencing.

Is a multi-model database a good way to meet this challenge? How well do databases like MongoDB and OrientDB meet this type of challenge?